# How to optimize multiple matching with regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write my first framework for writing bots for one website.

Now I'm writing a *class* that represents the message a user receives and I have a small problem.

This site has 2 types of messages: from users and from the site itself - **system** messages.
There are about 20 system messages: new order, new review, review deleted and so on.
Important: from the *HTML* side the messages are exactly the same. There are no differences between **user** and **system** messages, nor between the different types of **system** messages. That is, I can't determine the type of message during parsing.

I need to add a property `message_type` to the message object. As I said, they are not different from the *HTML* side, but the content itself is different. So I had to make 20 regular expressions. Each new message I loop through these regular expressions until I find `full_match()`.

Is there any way to optimize this process?

**UPD1:** I get only the text of the message and I need to determine the message type from this text.
Let me repeat: from the HTML side they are NOT different in any way. The user cannot distinguish a system message from an ordinary one (all questions about this misunderstanding are for the site developers).

For example:

System message about a new order: `User X paid for order number 12321.`

System message about a new review: `User X left a review for order number 12321.`

System message about opening a dispute: `User X opened a dispute on order number 12321.`

System message about closing a dispute: `Administrator X has closed the dispute for order number 12321.`

System message about partial refunds: `Administrator X refunded some funds to customer Y for order number 12321.`

There are more system messages, but I'll take these 5 as an example for now.
How I have the message type detection implemented:

```
class MessageType(Enum):
    """This object represents all types of system messages."""
    NEW_ORDER = 1
    NEW_REVIEW = 2
    DISPUTE_OPENED = 3
    DISPUTE_CLOSED = 4
    PARTIAL_REFUND = 5
    
    USER_MESSAGE = 0


# All message types and their regular expressions are listed here.
message_type_re = {
    MessageType.NEW_ORDER: re.compile(r"User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ paid for order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.NEW_REVIEW: re.compile(r"User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ left a review for order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.DISPUTE_OPENED: re.compile(r"User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ opened a dispute on order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.DISPUTE_CLOSED: re.compile(r"Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ closed the dispute for order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.PARTIAL_REFUND: re.compile(r"Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ refunded some funds to customer [a-zA-Z0-9]+ for order number [0-9]{5}\.")
}


class Message:
    """This object represents message."""
    def __init__(self, text: str, *args):
        self.text: str = text
        """Text of the message."""

        self.type = self.determine_message_type()
        """Type of the message"""

    def determine_message_type(self) -> MessageType:
        """This method determines message type."""
        for message_type in message_type_re:
            if message_type_re[message_type].fullmatch(self.text):
                return message_type
        return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE
```

Comment: By "optimize", do you mean that you are looking for a solution with better performance, or do you mean that you are looking for a solution that doesn't require a new regular expression per message? I think from a software maintenance point of view, your current solution is fine. There might be faster solutions than the regex matching, but they will be more complex. In the end, if there are 20 different types with different "characteristics", you will have to define those characteristics in your code at least once for your code to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: @He3lixxx, By "optimize" I mean more performance. If it can be achieved by avoiding regular expressions, why not?
Of course, 20 regular expressions will run through a loop quite quickly, and I am not writing any software that needs extremely fast execution.
But what if there were 100 different system messages? What if there were 1000?
Then it would take too much time to determine the type of one message, and sometimes these messages come at a rate of several dozens of them per second.

Comment: Alright. You can use the fact that the messages have a static prefix: Some start with "User", or "U", others start with "Administrator", or "A". Just checking the first character thus allows you to already rule out ~half of the regexes you would have to try. For the remaining messages, you would be looking for the first word that uniquely identifies the message. Your regex for the "username" does not allow spaces. Is that correct? If it is, I'd find the second space in the message, then look at the next word. From the samples we have so far, they allow uniquely identifying the message type.

Comment: @He3lixxx, I thought about it, but it's also possible for a user to write a post that starts with U, or even more so with A.
By the way, the user may well "fake" a message, which would cause this function to work falsely, but there is nothing to be done about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most optimized solution obviously depends on the actual system messages you can get, so given only the 5 samples from the question, I can only give a solution for these 5 samples.

In general, for the most performant solution, you'd want to reduce the amount of operations your program performs to categorize a string. You'd usually do this by finding elements in the message that allow you to quickly rule out most of the options, making sure that you only go to "heavy" computations for as few possibible message types as possible.

One attempt to do this can be based on the first word after the second space in the message. For a random user message, this will be an arbitrary character, but for a the 5 given system messages, we expect one specific character there. If the find that character, we were either unlucky and a user message just happened to contain that character, or we have a system message. For final confirmation, you'd still need to run the full regex match.

Overall, this approach would look like this:

```py
DiscriminatingWordCharToMessageType = {
    "p": MessageType.NEW_ORDER,
    "l": MessageType.NEW_REVIEW,
    "o": MessageType.DISPUTE_OPENED,
    "c": MessageType.DISPUTE_CLOSED,
    "r": MessageType.PARTIAL_REFUND,
}

def categorize_optimized(message_text: str) -> MessageType:
    first_space_index = message_text.find(" ")
    second_space_index = message_text.find(" ", first_space_index + 1)
    if second_space_index == -1:
        return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE  # doesn't have a second space -> can't be system message

    if second_space_index + 28 > len(message_text):
        return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE  # is shorter than the shortest system message
    
    try:
        guessed_message_type = DiscriminatingWordCharToMessageType[message_text[second_space_index + 1]]
    except KeyError:
        return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE
    
    if MessageTypeRegexes[guessed_message_type].fullmatch(message_text):
        return guessed_message_type
    
    return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE
```

Now, is that actually faster? You won't know until you actually measure. The actual pattern matching on `re` is likely implemented in optimized C code, so that our code has the disadvantage of being interpreted, and thus every python operation might be much slower than one operation of the pattern matching.

This script benchmarks both approaches. Keep in mind that the input data will heavily influence the results. In this version, input data is built with the assumption that most users create random messages, and no significant part of users creates messages that attempt to partly "impersonate" system messages in order to slow your program down.

```
import re
import random
import string
import timeit
from enum import Enum

class MessageType(Enum):
    NEW_ORDER = 1
    NEW_REVIEW = 2
    DISPUTE_OPENED = 3
    DISPUTE_CLOSED = 4
    PARTIAL_REFUND = 5
    
    USER_MESSAGE = 0


MessageTypeRegexes = {
    MessageType.NEW_ORDER: re.compile(r"User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ paid for order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.NEW_REVIEW: re.compile(r"User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ left a review for order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.DISPUTE_OPENED: re.compile(r"User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ opened a dispute on order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.DISPUTE_CLOSED: re.compile(r"Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ closed the dispute for order number [0-9]{5}\."),
    MessageType.PARTIAL_REFUND: re.compile(r"Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ refunded some funds to customer [a-zA-Z0-9]+ for order number [0-9]{5}\."),
}

MessageTypeFormatStrings = {
    MessageType.NEW_ORDER: "User {user_name} paid for order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.NEW_REVIEW: "User {user_name} left a review for order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.DISPUTE_OPENED: "User {user_name} opened a dispute on order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.DISPUTE_CLOSED: "Administrator {user_name} closed the dispute for order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.PARTIAL_REFUND: "Administrator {user_name} refunded some funds to customer {customer_name} for order number {order_number}.",
}

USER_MESSAGE_ALPHABET = string.printable
USER_NAME_ALPHABET = [*string.ascii_letters, *string.digits]

def generate_random_message() -> str:
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        format_string = random.choice(list(MessageTypeFormatStrings.values()))
        user_name = ''.join(random.choices(USER_NAME_ALPHABET, k=random.randint(5, 40)))
        order_number = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=5))
        customer_name = ''.join(random.choices(USER_NAME_ALPHABET, k=random.randint(5, 40)))
        return format_string.format(user_name=user_name, order_number=order_number, customer_name=customer_name)
    
    message_length = random.randint(10, 80)
    return ''.join(random.choices(USER_MESSAGE_ALPHABET, k=message_length))


def categorize_loop_regex(message_text: str) -> MessageType:
    for (message_type, regex) in MessageTypeRegexes.items():
        if regex.fullmatch(message_text):
            return message_type
    return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE


DiscriminatingWordCharToMessageType = {
    "p": MessageType.NEW_ORDER,
    "l": MessageType.NEW_REVIEW,
    "o": MessageType.DISPUTE_OPENED,
    "c": MessageType.DISPUTE_CLOSED,
    "r": MessageType.PARTIAL_REFUND,
}

def categorize_optimized(message_text: str) -> MessageType:
    first_space_index = message_text.find(" ")
    second_space_index = message_text.find(" ", first_space_index + 1)
    if second_space_index == -1:
        return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE  # doesn't have a second space -> can't be system message

    if second_space_index + 28 > len(message_text):
        return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE  # is shorter than the shortest system message
    
    try:
        guessed_message_type = DiscriminatingWordCharToMessageType[message_text[second_space_index + 1]]
    except KeyError:
        return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE
    
    # return guessed_message_type  # add to see how much time is spent in regex matching here
    if MessageTypeRegexes[guessed_message_type].fullmatch(message_text):
        return guessed_message_type
    
    return MessageType.USER_MESSAGE


def test():
    messages = [generate_random_message() for _ in range(10000)]
    try:
        for message in messages:
            assert categorize_loop_regex(message) == categorize_optimized(message)
    except AssertionError:
        print("fail")
    else:
        print("pass")


def benchmark(categorizer):
    messages = [generate_random_message() for _ in range(10000)]

    def categorize_all():
        for message in messages:
            categorizer(message)
    
    print(timeit.timeit(categorize_all, number=100))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Testing...")
    test()

    print("\nBenchmarking Regex Loop...")
    benchmark(categorize_loop_regex)

    print("\nBenchmarking Optimized Loop...")
    benchmark(categorize_optimized)
```

I get this output:

```
$ python3 messages.py
Testing...
pass

Benchmarking Regex Loop...
1.5220307029994729

Benchmarking Optimized Loop...
0.8915843009999662
```

So here, our approach of ruling out options before applying the regex reduces runtime by ~40%. If you're curious, when adding in the early `return guessed_message_type` to skip the final regex matching, the runtime goes down to ~0.45, so the "optimized" version still spends half its time in the final pattern matching operation.

Now, for the sake of actual real-world applications, if performance is a relevant criterion, I wouldn't use python here, but a language that is compiled to optimized machine code. This is the same benchmark code in C++:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include <string_view>
#include <span>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "ctre.hpp"  // https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions

enum MessageType {
    NEW_ORDER = 0,
    NEW_REVIEW = 1,
    DISPUTE_OPENED = 2,
    DISPUTE_CLOSED = 3,
    PARTIAL_REFUND = 4,

    USER_MESSAGE = -1,
};


MessageType categorize_loop_regex(std::string_view message) {
    if(ctre::match<R"(User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ paid for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()))
        return NEW_ORDER;

    if(ctre::match<R"(User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ left a review for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()))
        return NEW_REVIEW;

    if(ctre::match<R"(User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ opened a dispute on order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()))
        return DISPUTE_OPENED;

    if(ctre::match<R"(Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ closed the dispute for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()))
        return DISPUTE_CLOSED;

    if(ctre::match<R"(Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ refunded some funds to customer [a-zA-Z0-9]+ for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()))
        return PARTIAL_REFUND;

    return MessageType::USER_MESSAGE;
}

MessageType discriminating_word_char_to_message_type(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'p': return MessageType::NEW_ORDER;
        case 'l': return MessageType::NEW_REVIEW;
        case 'o': return MessageType::DISPUTE_OPENED;
        case 'c': return MessageType::DISPUTE_CLOSED;
        case 'r': return MessageType::PARTIAL_REFUND;
        default: return MessageType::USER_MESSAGE;
    }
}

MessageType categorize_optimized(std::string_view message) {
    auto first_space_it = std::find(message.begin(), message.end(), ' ');
    if(first_space_it == message.end()) {
        return MessageType::USER_MESSAGE;
    }

    auto second_space_it = std::find(first_space_it + 1, message.end(), ' ');
    if(std::distance(second_space_it, message.end()) < 28) {
        return MessageType::USER_MESSAGE;
    }

    MessageType guessed_message_type = discriminating_word_char_to_message_type(*(second_space_it + 1));
    if(guessed_message_type == MessageType::USER_MESSAGE) {
        return MessageType::USER_MESSAGE;
    }

    bool regex_match;
    switch(guessed_message_type) {
        case 0: regex_match = ctre::match<R"(User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ paid for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()); break;
        case 1: regex_match = ctre::match<R"(User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ left a review for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()); break;
        case 2: regex_match = ctre::match<R"(User [a-zA-Z0-9]+ opened a dispute on order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()); break;
        case 3: regex_match = ctre::match<R"(Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ closed the dispute for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()); break;
        case 4: regex_match = ctre::match<R"(Administrator [a-zA-Z0-9]+ refunded some funds to customer [a-zA-Z0-9]+ for order number [0-9]{5}\.)">(message.data()); break;
    }

    if(regex_match) {
        return guessed_message_type;
    }

    return MessageType::USER_MESSAGE;
}

void test(std::span<std::string> messages) {
    for(const auto& message :  messages) {
        if(categorize_optimized(message) != categorize_loop_regex(message)) {
            std::cout << "fail for \"" << message << "\"\n";
            std::cout << "optimized: " << categorize_optimized(message) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "naive loop: " << categorize_loop_regex(message) << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "pass\n";
}


template <auto categorizer>
void benchmark(std::span<std::string> messages) {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    size_t accumulator = 0;  // To disallow the compiler removing the computation

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        for(const auto& message : messages) {
            accumulator += categorizer(message);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "accumulator: " << accumulator << std::endl;

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;

    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream input_file("message_data.txt");
    if(!input_file) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open message_data.txt" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<std::string> messages;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(input_file, line)) {
        messages.push_back(line);
    }

    std::cout << "Testing..." << std::endl;
    test(messages);

    std::cout << "Benchmarking regex loop" << std::endl;
    benchmark<categorize_loop_regex>(messages);

    std::cout << "Benchmarking optimized loop" << std::endl;
    benchmark<categorize_optimized>(messages);
}
```

with this script to generate input data

```
import random
import string
from enum import Enum

class MessageType(Enum):
    NEW_ORDER = 1
    NEW_REVIEW = 2
    DISPUTE_OPENED = 3
    DISPUTE_CLOSED = 4
    PARTIAL_REFUND = 5
    
    USER_MESSAGE = 0


MessageTypeFormatStrings = {
    MessageType.NEW_ORDER: "User {user_name} paid for order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.NEW_REVIEW: "User {user_name} left a review for order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.DISPUTE_OPENED: "User {user_name} opened a dispute on order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.DISPUTE_CLOSED: "Administrator {user_name} closed the dispute for order number {order_number}.",
    MessageType.PARTIAL_REFUND: "Administrator {user_name} refunded some funds to customer {customer_name} for order number {order_number}.",
}

USER_MESSAGE_ALPHABET = string.printable
USER_NAME_ALPHABET = [*string.ascii_letters, *string.digits]

def generate_random_message() -> str:
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        format_string = random.choice(list(MessageTypeFormatStrings.values()))
        user_name = ''.join(random.choices(USER_NAME_ALPHABET, k=random.randint(5, 40)))
        order_number = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=5))
        customer_name = ''.join(random.choices(USER_NAME_ALPHABET, k=random.randint(5, 40)))
        return format_string.format(user_name=user_name, order_number=order_number, customer_name=customer_name)
    
    message_length = random.randint(10, 80)
    return ''.join(random.choices(USER_MESSAGE_ALPHABET, k=message_length))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("message_data.txt", "w") as f:
        for _ in range(10000):
            print(generate_random_message(), file=f)
```

It turns out that the `std::regex` implementation on my machine is rather slow, so I used [ctre](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions) (simply for it being the first header-only regex library I could find). Runtime on the same machine is reported as:

```
$ ./messages                                                      
Testing...
pass

Benchmarking regex loop
accumulator: 299000
elapsed time: 0.10054

Benchmarking optimized loop
accumulator: 299000
elapsed time: 0.104549
```

So here, with an optimized regex engine, the "optimization" approach does not make sense anymore, at least for the 6 message types we have. It might be different with thousands of different message types.

0.10s for 100*624004 characters means the categorizer processes ~600M characters per second, or requires ~4 cpu cycles per input character.

Given that the regex engine from the standard library was slow in C++, I tried to use google's re2 in the python benchmark, using the bindings from the `pyre2` and `google-re2` pip packages, but both didn't improve performance. I'm not aware of other, higher performance regex engines for pythons. I'm especially not aware of CTRE bindings for python.

In theory, if we were able to use CTRE in python, I'd think that our optimizations should not matter for performance or even make it worse, due to the python interpretation overhead.

For your program, I'd recommend just keeping the loops you have in your question. Their performance is still enough to process millions of messages per second, and I think it's highly unlikely that you'll have that much data to process, anyway.